# Unable to read repository at https://spotbugs.github.io/eclipse/content.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spotbugs

I try to install SpotBugs but below error appeared.

Unable to read repository at https://spotbugs.github.io/eclipse/content.xml.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

I use:
openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)

And:
Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Answer (score 2):

firstly can you try >> sudo update-ca-certificates -f

If not resolved, follow the below steps;

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
$ sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
$ sudo update-ca-certificates — fresh
```

References:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894979
- https://medium.com/@SelimEmreToy/java-lang-runtimeexception-2d3794a1c242

Good luck!